# can we automate flex android application using appium?

Tags: android, selenium, testing, mobile, appium

Mobile/Device:- samsung tab3
Os:- 4.4.2(Kitkat)
tool Appium.(Selenium)
application:- core5 Lexia reading

couldn't get the object tree in appium inspector window. So unable to pass the operation like click and send keys.
So please tell me the we can automate the flex android application using appium(Selenium) or not.

Help.